# List type mismatch element Object

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I'm trying to create a REST webservice using the Jersey ResourceConfig class.

But, I'm getting an error, which I can't understand.

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Product**

Code:

```
@Path("productcatalog")
public class ProductCatalogResource {
    private static List productCatalog;
    public ProductCatalogResource() {
        initializeProductCatalog();
    }
    @GET
    @Path("search/category/{category}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Product[] searchByCategory(@PathParam("category") String category) {
        List products = new ArrayList();
        for (Product p : productCatalog) { // OBJECT TYPE ERROR
            if (category != null && category.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getCategory())) {
                products.add(p);
            }
        }
        return products.toArray(new Product[products.size()]); // OBJECT TYPE ERROR
    }

    private void initializeProductCatalog() {
        if (productCatalog == null) {
            productCatalog = new ArrayList();
            productCatalog.add(new Product(id, name, category, unitPrice));
   }
}
```

The Product class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private double unitPrice;

    public Product() {} // needed for JAXB
    public Product(int id, String name, String category, double unitPrice) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use raw types. Change `private static List productCatalog` to `private static List<Product> productCatalog`

Comment: Thanks. Additionally I changed the return value: return (Product[]) products.toArray(new Product[products.size()]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you didnt write the type of list.

```
  private static List<Product> productCatalog;
```